# Deshabilitar día actual de Datepicker Jquery solo si es domingo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker, jquery-datepicker

Un saludo, quisiera saber de que manera deshabilitar que se pueda seleccionar el día actual de mi Datepicker solo sí es ese mismo domingo. Es decir, que puedan seleccionar otros domingos menos el mismo domingo del día actual. Ya logre deshabilitar el día actual, pero no logro hacer que solo sea el domingo actual. Gracias por su atención y espero puedan ayudarme, dejo mi código:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>     
        
          $(function () {
                   
          $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
           closeText: 'Cerrar',
           prevText: '< Ant',
           nextText: 'Sig >',
           currentText: 'Hoy',
           monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
           monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
           dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
           dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
           dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
           weekHeader: 'Sm',
           dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
           isRTL: false,
           showMonthAfterYear: false,
           yearSuffix: ''
           };
          $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
          $("#fecha").datepicker({
            
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            //Get today's date at midnight
            var today = new Date();
            today = Date.parse(today.getMonth()+1+'/'+today.getDate()+'/'+today.getFullYear());

            var selDate = Date.parse(dateText);

            if(selDate <= today) {
                //If the selected date was 
                $('#Date').val('');
                $(inst).datepicker('show');
            }
            },
            minDate: "+1D",
            maxDate: "+3M",
          });
          });
        
        
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Es el datepicker de jquery ui?

Comment: Hola, si es el datepicker de jquery ui, te recomiendo leer estos hilos de StackOverflow en su version angloparlante: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376987/disable-all-sundays-in-jquery-ui-calendar 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395558/highlight-disable-specific-days-in-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: Gracias @EdgarGc, ya los revise, también leí la documentación de Jquery, y entiendo como deshabilitar los días, sin embargo me falta realizar un if para deshabilitar solo el domingo actual, aunque no se como realizarlo.

Comment: @gaidyjg Efectivamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a los que me ayudaron, pude resolverlo creando una condición externa y funciona de esta manera:

- Declaro las variables de días, para (los días arrojan números, domingos arrojan un 0 y en adelante hasta sábado que arroja un 6)
- Para omitir el día domingo actual (solo cuando sea el mismo domingo) y que puedan seleccionar los domingos posteriores cree una condición si `day == 0` (que pertenece al día domingo) agregando al datepicker un `minDate: "+1D"`.

Dejo el código del script por sí a alguien más le es útil.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    var time = new Date();
    var day = time.getDay();
    var strDate = time.getFullYear() + "/" + (time.getMonth()+1) + "/" + time.getDate();

    $(function () {
      if(day == 0){
        $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
        closeText: 'Cerrar',
        prevText: '< Ant',
        nextText: 'Sig >',
        currentText: 'Hoy',
        monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''
        };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
        $("#fecha").datepicker({            
          minDate: "+1D"
        });
      } 
    });      
    </script>
```